# IntelliJ IDEA Scala plugin's syntax highlighting displays Scala packages in red

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

This is a bit weird, I've got IntelliJ IDEA 10, a fairly recent Scala plugin on it and sbt 0.7.7. I've been using the same setup on the same project for a while and syntax highlighting worked perfect.

After a few clean/compiles from sbt (I'm not really sure about the action), everything from Scala._ is red. For instance, `List()` is red but when I import `scala.collection._` it gets fixed. The project compiles without any problems in both IDEA and SBT. What may be the problem?

(new/other projects are OK on the same setup so I guess I've messed up something but I have no clue where to look for it)

Thanks

Comment: Maybe better ask this on the Idea Scala plugin forum.

Comment: The jetbrains forum is probably a better place to ask: http://devnet.jetbrains.net/community/idea/scala -- in any case, did you check the project module's dependencies? maybe something got invalid? also make sure you don't have some naming conflict, e.g. shadowing scala.Predef ?

Comment: @Sciss it was exactly this, a jar I had added self-contained Scala libs. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I've never found a single solution to this, so i generally **try all the things**.

1. sbt gen-idea (to recreate IDEA project meta-data)
2. File > Invalidate Caches ... > Invalidate and Restart

After invalidating caches, upon restart IDEA will re-index all of your class files.

Usually I'll try

```
sbt> clean
sbt> gen-idea
```

Then if it didn't work go for invalidating caches. If that still doesn't work (and it almost always does) try deleting the following directories and then perform #1/#2 from above again:

- target
- project/target
- .idea
- .idea_modules

Comment: +1 (for the 'reality' of this post).  wow that's ugly.  But unfortunately feels likely necessary.  Life is tough IDE and build-tool wise in scala-land.

Answer (score 2):

at project Settings, add the jars to its dependencies of IDE, then you will get the red away.
SBT is one thing, IDEA is another, they use their own way to compile scala.  some sbt plugin for idea is also something that just hook sbt command line to idea's panel.

Answer (score 2):

This sometimes happens to me when the SBT and IDEA projects get out of sync. Simply run the [SBT Idea processor](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea) again - this regenerates your Idea project files.